# How to print Content of currently Executing file C++?

Tags: c++, operating-system

How to print all the content of the currently executing file from in itself in C++?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // some code that print current file.
}
```

#### expected output:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // some code that print current file.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there can be many ways possible, easy one.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string more = "more ";
    more.append(__FILE__);
    system(more.c_str());

}
```

#### Output:

```sh
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string more = "more ";
    more.append(__FILE__);
    system(more.c_str());

}
```